# Match all words regex expression excepting urls

Tags: regex

I need to match all words from a tweet which are not urls (starting with https), hashtags (starting with #) or other characters such as .,;/

I am using

```
(?!https|[\\t])\b[aA-zZ]+
```

but it is not working as expected.

Is there any other way to extract only words not starting with special characters or utls?

Comment: Can you provide a few tweets and show what you expect to get from them? As someone who doesn't use tweeter I have no idea what the data is so creating a regex for it would be impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I a lookbehind assertion is supported, you might use:

```
(?<!\S)(?!https?:\/\/)\w\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?!https?:\/\/)` Negative lookahead, assert not http:// or https:// directly to the right
- `\w\S*` Match a single word character followed by optional non whitespace characters

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gfeM02/1).

Without a lookbehind and a capture group:

```
(?:\s|^)(?!https?:\/\/)(\w\S*)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1vZSvM/1).